# Magento 2.1: How to reference/replace template of an existing child block/alias?

Tags: layout, magento-2.1, blocks

I am trying to change de default product stock availability text to my own by using a custom phtml file. I want to overwrite "module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml" therefore I created a custom module with catalog_product_view.xml with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>  
    <referenceContainer name="product.info.type">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Type\Simple" name="product.info.description" as="product_type_data" template="Sixways_Estdelivery::displayStockStatus.phtml">
        <argument name="cacheable" xsi:type="boolean">false</argument>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>       
</body>
```

This works great but the exception.log file is filling up with this error:

> main.CRITICAL: Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException: The
>   element 'product.info.type' already has a child with alias
>   'product_type_data' in
>   /staging/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Structure.php:611

I tried leaving `product_type_data` away but that makes the original and the custom phtml appear instead of only the custom one.

What is the correct way of overwriting `name="product.info.simple" as="product_type_data"` in `referenceContainer name="product.info.type"`?

Answer (score 1):

try with

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>  
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.description">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Sixways_Estdelivery::displayStockStatus.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>       
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this just now but it doesn't seem to work. Everything I tried without <referenceContainer name="product.info.type"> didn't work so far.

Comment: strange.. It seams to work in the core https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Paypal/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_create_index.xml

Comment: Mmm... I have no idea what i'm doing wrong here. The original block is defined in https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view_type_simple.xml at line 11