# Magento 2.1.8 All Pages Display Blank

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2.1.8 Site All Pages Display Blank.

Link: http://dev.controllermodz.co.uk/controllermodz/

In Google Chrome Console Displays Error: Error parsing header X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block, 1; mode=block: expected semicolon at character position 14. The default protections will be applied.

[image]

Comment: Set your store in developer mode and enable PHP error reporting and check the error and exception logs.

Comment: Hii #anshu into Log we Found  : main.CRITICAL: exception 'Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException' with message 'The element 'product.info.type' already has a child with alias 'product_type_data'' in /home/controllermodz/public_dev/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Structure.php

Comment: Set your store in developer mode and enable PHP error reporting

Comment: Yes , I Do It and Upper error Come

Comment: Hello , In To Error Reporting Blank Page Come . No Errors Display

Comment: check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154480/magento-2-1-how-to-reference-replace-template-of-an-existing-child-block-alias